# a simple way to break a String into a list of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, string

so i am still learning java and recently i needed a method that does this :

it breaks the string wherever it finds a certain charecter, lets say a 'space' is where it breaks

```
String s= "aaa bbb eejj ,hhre";
String[] list = breaktheString(s);
for(String g : list){
   System.out.println(g);
}
```

it shows this:

```
aaa
bbb
eejj
,hhre
```

thats it but i need to write this to meet the quality standards but thats actually all i have so just ignore this and act like i didnt write it down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
String s= "aaa bbb eejj ,hhre";
String[] list = s.split(" ");
for(String g : list){
   System.out.println(g);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're learning I don't want to give you the complete answer in case this is homework, but i'll give you a couple of hints. You can check if a certain character is in a certain part of a string with an if like this:

```
//checks if space is in the first position of str
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = " hello";
        if (' ' == str.charAt(0) {
            System.out.println("the first character is a space);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoted as `str` is undefined, and if it's a `String` (as implied by the name) it isn't an array and so you couldn't do `str[0]` (and comparing `String`s using `==` is also not a good idea, and definitely not when one operand is a `char` instead).

Comment: woops! sorry there I completely forgot that java doesn't support the string[0] thing! Rather than downvoting and being relatively negative, you could always try editing the posts! It is quite helpful and makes the community a lot more positive (and it doesn't cost reputation!)

Comment: Wasn't trying to be negative.  I appreciate you making an attempt to answer.  I'd just rather there wasn't a spread of misinformation.  Thanks for editing (downvote now removed).  And yes, I could (and do) edit to fix typos, formatting, for clarity, etc.  But for misinformation I'd rather point out the error to the original poster so they can either tell me I'm wrong or learn and not repeat the same misinformation elsewhere.  I'd also rather someone did this to my posts.

Comment: yeah I understand, text can't convey emotion very well so intent can get blurry and then two well-meaning people can misinterpret each other. Thanks for helping me spot the error, I wouldn't have found it without you lol :D